# Covariant Stared Vector Spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

I reading john Lee's book entitled "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" and on page 311

$$T^{k}\!\!\left(V^{*}\right)=V^{*}\!\!\times\!\!V^{*}...V^{*}\;\;k\text{-times}$$

is defined as the vector space of all covariant $k$-tensors on $V$.  The stared version of $V$ seems to appear out of nowhere, so my questions are:

What does $V^{*}$ represent?

What is the "*" in $V^{*}$ supose to represent?

Is it true that the vector space $V$ must first be specified before $V^{*}$ can be constructed?

What does an element of $V^{*}$ look like and how does it compare to and element of $V$?

Comment: It's the dual space.

Comment: Given a vector space $V$, $V^*$ is the space of all linear map $f: V\to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ${}^*$ in $V^*$ means "dual". The space $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$, which consists of all linear functionals on $V$. Linear functionals on $V$ are linear maps $F : V\to \Bbb R$.